# How I can use $getDownloadURL() promise with ng-repeat Angularjs 1.6

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase-storage

I'm building an SPA and I'm using Angularjs 1.6 with firebase (database and storage).

I want to use an image from firebase storage on my html page.

To achieve that
I am using a directive and it's working fine on some pages, but if I use `ng-repeat` to loop and to dynamically paste link to an image which is saved on 
a firebase storage, I stumble into an issue.

I am using `$getDownloadURL()` to get a promise pending, and after some time it resolves, but the page is already loaded and I experience a collapse.

Can I change the promise of `$getDownloadURL()`?

**My code :**

```js
angular.module('module', ['firebase']).controller('someCtrl', someCtrl).directive('firebaseSrc', FirebaseStorageDirective);

function FirebaseStorageDirective($firebaseStorage, firebase) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 99,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('firebaseSrc', function (newFirebaseSrcVal) {
          if (newFirebaseSrcVal !== '') {
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(newFirebaseSrcVal);
            var storage = $firebaseStorage(storageRef);
            storage.$getDownloadURL().then(function  getDownloadURL(url) {
              element[0].src = url;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
FirebaseStorageDirective.$inject = ['$firebaseStorage', 'firebase'];
```

```html
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<img firebase-src="{{item.somePath}}" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am not using a directive but totally the issue is same.. did you got a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `attrs.$observe`, the directive attribute needs to use `{{ }}` interpolation to evaluate Angular Expressions:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('firebaseSrc', function (newFirebaseSrcVal) {
```

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<img firebase-src="{{item.somePath}}" />
</li>
</ul>
```

---

Or use `scope.$watch` to directly evaluate an Angular Exression:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.firebaseSrc, function (newFirebaseSrcVal) {
```

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<img firebase-src="item.somePath" />
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: unfortunately it's doesn't work for me, if I change to $scope.$watch I catch "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined", but if I add to my code "scope: true" I catch error "Error: [$compile:multidir]"

Comment: Use `scope.$watch`. `scope` without the `$` dollar sign.

Comment: Thank you! I solved this issue and rewrite directive,code I added below maybe to someone will help, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have my firebaseDB and I get json file where item.path (into html) it's path to picture and item.picture[0] it's first name of picture from array pictures in folder path

My new module

```js
MODULE:
angular.module('myModule', ['firebase']).directive('firebaseImage', FirebaseImageDirective);

DIRECTIVE:
function FirebaseImageDirective($firebaseStorage, firebase) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      priority: 99,
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.descr = attrs['fireImageAlt'];
            var myRef = attrs['fireImagePath'];
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(myRef);
            var storage = $firebaseStorage(storageRef);
            storage.$getDownloadURL().then(function getDownloadURL(url) {
              scope.path = url;
        });
      },
      template: "<img src='{{path}}' alt='{{descr}}'/>",
      replace: true
    };
  }
FirebaseImageDirective.$inject = ['$firebaseStorage', 'firebase'];
```

```html
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <firebase-image fire-image-path="{{item.path+'/'+ item.picture[0]}}"
                    fire-image-alt="{{item.species + ' ' + item.name}}">
    </firebase-image>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: function uploadImage(fileData, storagePath) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var metadata = {
   contentType: 'image/jpeg,image/png',
  };
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  var uploadTask = storageRef.child(storagePath + '/' + fileData.files[0].name).put(fileData.files[0], metadata);
  var tangRef = storageRef.child(storagePath + '/' + fileData.files[0].name);
  var urlData = tangRef
   .getDownloadURL()
   .then(function(url) {    
    defer.resolve(url);
    return defer.promise;
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
    return defer.promise;
   });
  return urlData; }